# Web Api AuthorizeAttribute access query string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorize

I have a web API method, that is defined like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id:int}/whatever")]
[AuthorizeClass]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> functionName(int id, [FromBody] JToken data)
{           
    //Do something....
    return Ok();
}

public class AuthorizeClass : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //Do something...
        }
}
```

In the `OnAuthorization` method I need to find the value of the id parameter, which seems to be held in the querystring.

I can find the whole string, but I want to specifically find it by its name, rather than deconstructing the query string - is this possible?

EDIT:

I have tried the answers in this question:
[Accessing QueryString in a custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805920/accessing-querystring-in-a-custom-authorizeattribute)

but they just return an empty array

Comment: My bad, I linked he wrong answer.  Your `id` variable is in route data not the querystring.  Look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941399/16363

Comment: @Mark that worked - if you mark that as the answer I will accept it....